# a href click not triggering in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        $(function() {

            $.getJSON("companies.json", function(response) {

                var html = '<table id="tbl">';
                response.businesses.forEach(function(row) {
                    html += '<tr><td><a href="#" class="move" idname="' + row.id + '">' + row.id + '</a></td><td>' + row.name;
                });
                html += '</table>';

                $("#tabledata").html(html);
            });


            $(".move").click(function() {

                var $id = $(this).attr("idname");

                $.getJSON("companies.json", function(response) {


                    $.map(response.businesses, function(obj) {
                        if (obj.id == $id)
                            console.log(obj);
                        return obj; // or return obj.name, whatever.
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="tabledata" class='left'></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
```

Please help?

Comment: could you provide the HTML as well

Comment: have you tried `$('.move').on('click',function(){})`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `.move` element is added to your page dynamically, you have to make use of [jQuery's `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to *delegate* the event to an ancestor of the `.move` element which does exist when your JavaScript first loads.

```
$(document).on('click', '.move', function() { ... });
```

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

You can read more about jQuery's event delegation [here](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 2):

If you use event delegation, your problem goes away (and your app becomes more performant and less prone to memory leaks).

```
// Only do this once, when your page loads...
$(document.body).on('click', '.move', function (ev) {
    // This is the link that was clicked.
    var $targ = $(ev.target);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('#tabledata').on('click', '.move', function(e) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the event isn't being triggered is because the event is only added to elements that exist on the page when you call the `.click()` method.

Instead, you can use event delegation:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.move', function (ev) {
    var $targ = $(ev.target);
});
```

which really says: call the function when any element that matches `.move` that's inside `document.body` is clicked.

*I know others have said this already but I wanted to make event delegation clearer.*